# Touch issue during UIView Animation

Tags: iphone, uianimation

I am animating UIView when user touches on custom dropdown to show picker View from bottom side.UIView contains Pickerview...so when I change it's frame to move upwards.I get what I want, but pickerView doesn't recognize touch !(see screenshot below)

code is like this

```
    CGRect pickerFrame=self.pickerSheet.frame;
    CGRect viewFrame=self.view.frame;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:SHEET_ANIMATION_DURATION];
//change Frame of View containing UIPickerView

pickerFrame.origin.y=202+animatedDistance;
viewFrame.origin.y-=animatedDistance;//animated distance is value by which view needs to move upward.
[self.pickerSheet setFrame:pickerFrame];
[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Zzm.png)

Comment: But how you have created the UIPickerView ??? Paste code of it.

Comment: @SurjitJoshi through IB...& i am adding it runtime in    self.view[self.view addSubview:self.pickerSheet];
 [self.pickerSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 460, 320, 258)];

Answer (score 0):

first of all, ++please**, stop using this animation declaration, and bedin use new, block animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:SHEET_ANIMATION_DURATION 
                          delay:0 
                        options:nil 
                     animations:^{
                         pickerFrame.origin.y=202+animatedDistance;
                         viewFrame.origin.y-=animatedDistance;
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOO f){
                         //any actions after animation ended
                     }];
```

Second, I think your problem is somewhere else. May by, you implementing your touches or picker wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please start using the new , better animation block , but I think there is something missing in your code , you need to put the code below :

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

Put this code in  options in the new animation block , or find a way to put it in the old animation block